# kendo multiselect set value with json duplicates

Tags: json, ajax, kendo-ui, setvalue, kendo-multiselect

I'm using kendo multiselect and I'm trying to set some preselected options from json results like this (in the complete function of ajax):

```
$("#edit").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(users.split(","));
```

users is a string (of values) like this: 1,5,6,3.

The problem is that when I try to set those values I get duplicates in the multiselect front end.

(I've also tried giving values like this:

```
 $("#edit").data("kendoMultiSelect").value([1,5,6,3]);
```

same thing happend).

I've been searching the web but I really can't find anything.
Thanks for any help

Comment: can you show more infomation, your kendo multiselect configuration ?

Comment: `code`$("#edit").kendoMultiSelect({
      placeholder: "Select...",
      dataTextField: "NAME",
      dataValueField: "CODE",
      filter: "startswith",
      dataSource: {
       transport: {
        read: {
         dataType: "json",
         url: "tasks_vessels.php",
         serverFiltering: false,
         type: "GET"
        }
       }
      }
    });`code`
This is before my ajax call and in my ajax call complete I set those values

Comment: Your configurations seems good, is this ajax call is called multiples times ?

Comment: Yes, in order to create the string users like the above (1,5,6,3)